# Problems rendering images in Chrome/Firefox/Safari

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, images, safari

I noticed recently that some web images look pixelated and gradients look dithered. PNG images seem to have "JPEG artifacts." I never had this problem before and I don't remember making any big changes on my laptop. These are what I've done so far:

- Disabled and then uninstalled browser extensions
- Updated Flash
- System Restore (up to 2 months back)
- Reinstalled all browsers
- Turned off my antivirus/antispyware

To isolate the problem, I asked a friend to visit a website that I was having this problem with on his desktop. Here's my screenshot vs. his (both in the latest version of Chrome):

[image]

[image]

When I view local images on either Chrome, FF or Safari though, they appear fine. When I save the problem images locally, they retain their distorted quality.

At first, I thought it might be a graphics card issue but graphics in games seem to be fine (I checked WoW, League of Legends, Heroes of Newerth, Bad Company2, MW2). I first noticed this when I posted some screenshots to an SU question last Aug 12.

What could be wrong? What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a 3G modem it could be your service provider is reducing the quality of the images to conserve bandwidth, I had this issue with t-mobile in the UK.

Comment: For my laptop, I am using a 3G modem.

Comment: Then I guess that could be your issue, I think it's common practice on the mobile operators.  They route all your traffic through a proxy server that reduces the quality of images, if your running windows with the ISP's software there might be a setting to tell them to stop it.

Comment: I forgot, under IE in windows shift+R will usually load the full quality image although I did have some issues with certain websites. Also it's a good way to get through your bandwidth cap.

Comment: Unfortunately, they haven't responded to my ticket yet. I tried downloading the background image of the website in the screenie above using a download manager (DAP) and I got the non-distorted version.

Comment: Who is your provider?

Comment: Well I managed to isolate the problem by connecting through another ISP. Images looked crisp and clear.

Comment: OK, I suppose you could add some detail about your ISP to your question and maybe someone who uses them might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Kaze Have a look at this page http://www.istorya.net/forums/networking-and-internet/407355-sun-broadband-using-lossy-image-compression-as-of-06-27-2011-a.html

Comment: No prob, it looks like it's quite a recent thing and there are lots of unhappy customers.  Time to vote with your feet maybe or at least hassle their tech support.

Comment: I'll go with hassling their tech support. :D I also found a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, I "changed" Google's user agent string. I got the idea from [this Knol](http://knol.google.com/k/warren-l/google-chrome-change-user-agent-to/187t5jnwvnu9d/6#) and this [other article](http://lifehacker.com/5050497/change-google-chromes-user-agent-string).

1. Create a **shortcut** to the Chrome application.
2. Right-click > **Properties**
3. Change **Target** to:

   `C:\Users\Em-em\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-agent="SomethingElse"`

I'll just use this shortcut to launch Chrome (at least until my ISP fixes things).

There's an extension for Firefox called "User Agent Switcher" though I don't think it's been updated to work with the latest FF release.